# Incorrect border rendering when using css transform in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a simple CSS arrow like this:

```
.arrow-brown {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border-top: 6px solid #39170b;
    border-right: 6px solid #39170b;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

In Firefox the borders are not rendered correctly, two thin white lines  are appearing accross the border width. Is there any workaround to get rid of them??

Here's the rendered picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUsoQ.png

And here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/w2s9gp8w/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can give a try to draw the borders via `box-shadow` or via `linear-gradient`

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.box-shadow {
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  box-shadow: inset -18px 18px #39170b;
}
.arrow-brown {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 18px solid #39170b;
  border-right: 18px solid #39170b;
}
.gradient {
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #39170b, #39170b) top right no-repeat, linear-gradient(to top, #39170b, #39170b) top left no-repeat;
  background-size: 18px 100%, 100% 18px;
}
th {
  color:red;
  }
th:last-of-type {
  color:#54A719;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Tests on rotated shapes</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>border</th>
      <th>box-shadow</th>
      <th>linear-gradient</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="arrow-brown"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="box-shadow"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="gradient"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/GZoKRj

Answer (score 4):

That worked for me:

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues in Firefox with borders not being rendered correctly when using `transform` (`scale` to be specific). Adding a really tiny `border-radius` solved the issue for me.

```
border-radius: 0.01px;
```