# Firefox border rendering css arrow bug

Tags: html, css, firefox, border

In Firefox, I'm having an issue where the css generated arrow renders the border properties with a cut-through outline at the center point. Is there a fix for this?

It renders perfectly fine in all other modern browsers where the border outline isn't visible and shows a clear arrow.

The bug is only visible in Firefox.

**All other browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera, IE11):**

[image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

```css
    .bx-prev, .bx-next {
      border-right: 15px solid green;
      border-bottom: 15px solid green;
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      transition: .25s all;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 10000;
    }
    
    .bx-prev {
      transform: rotate(135deg);
      position: absolute;
      top: 120px;
      left: 220px;
    }
    
    .bx-next {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      position: absolute;
      top: 120px;
      right: 420px;
    }
```

```html
    <a class="bx-prev"></a>
    <a class="bx-next"></a>
```

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826845/incorrect-border-rendering-when-using-css-transform-in-firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `translateZ(1px)` with *rotate* property value

```
transform:translateZ(1px) rotate(-45deg)
```

Comment: Wow, a simple fix.Thank you so much for the answer. Firefox needs to incorporate this render fix to the transform property like the rest of the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be, how Firefox is translate the element using the `matrix` value in `transform` property.

Another way to solve such things is making a svg element or getting one from [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=arrow), download the .svg file. Using https://www.figma.com, to easily manipulate it and voilá.